# Is it called an instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, terminology, object

Say I have a function.

```
function foo(){
    //do stuff
}
```

And then I create an object of that function.

```
var fooObj = new foo();
```

What is `fooObj` called? An instance, An object instance, or something else entirely? Pardon the newbie question, but I am rather new to prototype based programming(and all programming really).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fooObj` is an object and it is also an instance of the `foo` prototype.

Though javascript doesn't technically have classes, many would also call `fooObj` an object of the `foo` class because it works somewhat similarly to classes in other languages.

Comment: This is not correct. prototype is a property of a constructor. fooObj is an instance of the foo constructor, not the foo constructor's prototype which is itself is an object or instance of something else.

Comment: I didn't say it was an instance of the foo constructor's prototype.  I said it was an instance of the prototype.  The prototype is the template for the object and using `new` makes an object from the prototype and calls the constructor.

Comment: Sorry. I meant "not an instance of the foo constructor's prototype." Should have been more clear. It can be thought of the way you describe but really prototype is just a backup object that gets referred to when you try to call a method that's not directly attached to the instance. It works like a backup object but serves as an inheritance mechanism. constructors create instances and they have prototypes. Instances have constructors with prototypes they inherit from. It matters when explaining why prototype methods can't access internal vars that this.<method> properties can.